# Animate hamburger button on query close selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu with an animating button, now I've made it so that the drop down menu can be closed upon clicking a content wrapper container div but the problem is it doesn't account for animating the button back to close position, below  is my HTML and J's code

```
function myFunction(x) {
/* This controls the animating function */
 x.classList.toggle("change");
/* This controls the menu close and open */
 var x = document.getElementById('Menu-cont');
if (x.style.height === "230px") {
        x.style.height = "0px";

    } else {
        x.style.height = "230px";
    }
}
/* This is a way to close menu click a container wrapper div */
document.querySelector('.content-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function(){ closeNav(); })
function closeNav() { 
var x = document.getElementById('Menu-cont').style.height = "0px"; 
}
```

I want animating button to animate back to close on after clicking wrapper div

this is animating html and css

```
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>



.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `myFunction(x)` to

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("my-icon")
  x.classList.toggle("change");

  var y = document.getElementById('Menu-cont');
  if (y.style.height === "230px") {
     y.style.height = "0px";

  } else {
     y.style.height = "230px";
  }
}
```

and `closeNav()` function to

```
function closeNav() { 
   //actually you don't need this function. Just call myFunction
   myFunction();
}
```

and add `id` to your `.my-icon` div

```
<div class="menu-icon" id="my-icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mustafa thank you, but it just makes the icon animate and doesn't necessarily close the navigation. 

Comment: I have made more progress using this  
                     document.querySelector('.content-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function(){ closeNav();})
function closeNav() { 
var x = document.getElementById('Menu-cont').style.height = "0px"; 
var y = document.getElementById('my-icon').classList.toggle("change");
}.                     Only problem is clicking the content wrapper div make icon toggle

Answer (score 0):

Did some more digging and this solved the problem
var y = document.getElementById('my-icon').classList.remove("change");
}